# Loopback js connector rest with async / await

Tags: async-await, loopbackjs

I am using the loopback-connector-rest (version 5.2.0) in order to invoke a third party API.

Even though i successfully invoke the API, it seems that i cannot get the response using async await operation.

```
res = await app.models.coupon.invoke({...});
```

I couldn't find an example with async await in the current docs.
Am i missing something?

Thanks.

**Update**

As it turns out everything was working as expected. The problem arised from the fact that i was invoking the third party API inside an async loop using await Promise.all() but i was trying to get the promises before all promises got resolved/rejected.

Thanks everyone for your time.

Comment: Do you use this function inside an `async` function ?? I think the problem is that `async` functions are returning a `Promise`, and the `await` is just syntactic sugar to remove callback hell. If your function itself is `async`, you CAN call `await` inside it, but if your function is not `async`, you should treat it as a function returning promise and just use the standard Promise syntax.   `app.models.coupon.invoke({...}).then((result) => { doSomethingWith(result); })`

Comment: AFAICT, the latest version of loopback-connector-rest is 3.3.0 and support for Promises/await was added all the way back in version 1.8.0 in April 2015. 

See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-rest/blob/master/CHANGES.md.

You are saying that your loopback-connector-rest version is 5.2.0, where did you get it from?